# Password Manager with an Android Version and no Browser Plugins

Tags: windows, android, password-manager

*First post on Software Recommendations, so be nice please.*

I'm looking for a Password Manager that works on a Windows 7/10 machine, and also has an associated Android App. An Apple App is a bonus, but not essential.

I've tried LastPass and Dashlane, but they're fraught with "useful" features that I'm never going to use. I don't need my Credit Card information stored, I don't **want** my forms on websites auto-filled, and I definitely don't want websites to automatically log me in with my fingerprint. I want to go in to the program, copy a stored password, and paste it manually in to a password field. *That's it.*

At work we use KeePass which seems almost ideal, however as the database file is shared among numerous staff here, I wouldn't be able to store personal passwords in it too. It also uses a local database file, so I doubt I could get access it from an Android device.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So it needs to be stored in the cloud? Even if it's a local database that you just put in dropbox to access?

Comment: Would I need to keep exporting it back out of the Dropbox to "update" on my Andriod device, or would it keep up-to-date automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Since it sounds like you already like KeePass, why not use that? You can start a new (personal) database, with a different password/key/etc and have KeePass load both.

If the personal DB was a v 1.x DB, there's lots of Android apps that will open it. There are iPhone apps for it too.

There's a pretty good list of the apps on the [KeePass-Homepage](http://keepass.info/download.html) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KeePass). Basically, Windows/Mac/Linux/iPhone/Android/Blackberry10/ChromeOS.

You can always store the personal DB on a USB or something you can carry around with you...

Comment: Additionally, the KeePass mobile apps usually have the ability to read a database file from Dropbox or Google Drive by caching a local copy that is synced with every access.